# What is the difference between NSBundle bundleWithURL URLforResource and NSBundle mainBundle PathforResource

Tags: objective-c, nsbundle

I have the following code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"play" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

The code above gets from mainBundle (Application Bundle) a file play.mp3 that is stored locally in my project

I have never used bundleWithURL and URLforResource could anyone explain to me what the code below does exactly? Any help appreciated.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"CloudResources" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
```

Comment: What do you think the code does after reading the documentation? Splitting the compound statement into separate statements might help.

Comment: @Willeke Well NSBundle *bundle = code returns a bundle for sure. The other part gets me confused because when i see URL i expect a url like www.google.com...

Comment: Both `pathForResource:ofType:` and `URLForResource:withExtension:` return the reference to the same resource. The former as `String` path, and the latter – the recommended API – as `URL`.

Comment: @Willeke The documentation says bundleWithURL:
Returns an NSBundle object that corresponds to the specified file URL. So it is just a file URL? like /documents/etc/ ? When i see file URL i expect something like www.server.com/file.mp3 am i wrong?

Comment: More reading: the returned URL is a [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc). "An object that represents the location of a resource, such as an item on a remote server or the path to a local file."

Comment: Another good hint might be [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)